# What is the difference between "work on computer" and "work on the computer"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I have heard people say both *work on computer* and *work on the computer*. For example:

> I work from home because I work **on computer**.
>
> I work from work because **I work on the computer**.

Is there any difference in meaning between the two? If there isn't any, then which one is more common?

Answer (score -1):

The first is possible but not idiomatic.

The second is better, assuming you meant to write:

> I work from home because I work on the computer.

But really I’d expect to hear other versions like:

> I work from home as my work is all on the computer.
>
> I work from home because all my work is all online.

Comment: I can't say exactly why, but I don't think OP's first version is even "possible", syntactically speaking. That's to say I think it's ***ungrammatical***, not just ***non-idiomatic***. You can *work on computer science*, for example, but you can't dispense with an article if it's just the noun ***computer***.